# Finding conditional pdf of $Z$ given $X=x$ where $Z=X+Y$

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

Finding conditional probability density function (pdf) of $Z$ given $X=x$ where $Z=X+Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables.

Trivially $Z$ is normal. But $Z$ and $X$ are not independent.

When means and variances of $X$ and $Y$ are given, how could I get the conditional pdf of $Z$ given $X=x$?

I have tried to calculate using the definition of pdf of normal random variable, but it was so messy.
Any hint for it?

Comment: You should have no problem writing the joint distribution of the correlated/dependent $Z$ and $X$. To determine their correlation coefficient, i.e. their covariance, remember $E(XZ) = E(X(X+Y)) = E(X^2) + E(XY)$ etc and from there you can derive the conditional you want. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/561189/15941) that the OP asked on math.SE about one hour earlier.

Comment: Please don't cross post on multiple SE sites.

Comment: Sorry! I never known the rule.

Answer (score 1):

When $(X,Y)$ is a pair of independent random variables and $Z=f(X,Y)$ for some Borelian (function) $f$, then one has a family of conditional distributions ${\cal L}(Z \mid X=x)$ which is simply obtained by defining ${\cal L}(Z \mid X=x)$ as being the law of $f(x,Y)$.

In your exercise $f(x,Y)=x+Y$ has the Gaussian distribution ${\cal N}(x+\mu, \sigma^2)$ if $Y \sim {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.